# Visual Studio 2013 uses too high CPU

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (with Update 5) Ultimate on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.
I encounter the problem that my CPU always reaches and maintains about 25% every time I turn it on. I heard some people suggest that disabling `Browser Link` can fix this situation. However, my `Browser Link` button cannot be opened because it has been disabled, how do I fix this situation?

[image: Visual Studio Processes]

P/s: I followed the suggestion on Google to disable the `Source Control` plug-in (set to "`None`") but the situation is still not fixed!

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Task Manager, you can right-click on the Visual Studio line under Background processes, choose "Details", and once there, right-click again on the Visual Studio line (it should already be highlighted) and lower the priority of the process.

Could render it sluggish, though, but it'll ease up on the CPU.

To access Details on any given application, it must not be in the foreground.

Comment: I have just followed your instructions, the result is it increased to 26% and then back and remained at 25%.

Comment: How many Visual Studio background processes do you see in Task Manager? There could be several: one for the UI, one for each of the coding tasks you're currently working on. Any one of them could use a lot of CPU, most probably one that's active, i.e. the project you're working on at the moment. Are you compiling right now?

Comment: I am compiling ```expat``` to build ```Apache``` for ```Windows```. And there is only 1 Visual Studio process for that project.

Comment: You *could* install Process Hacker on your PC (I install it on all my PC, right after install/reinstall, and I use it daily), which is a *monitoring*, not hacking, tool. Look it up and install it, then run it. Select the Visual Studio line, right-click and in the Misc section, click on Reduced working set. This should work. Visual Studio has always been CPU-intensive anyway, but it could help.